# how can i make the updated database reaches all users?

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I am developing  a menu app for restaurant , I want the user to be able to add a new dish (new row in a table) and when the row is added to the database all other users (who have the app in their device)can see the new update.

I want to use SQLite. is that possible if yes, how?

Comment: You'll need a remote database, served through web services.

Answer (score 0):

For such kind of scenario, you need to store the new menu item from a user on backend database (a database which is hosted on an external server) of your application, and all the other users using the application will get that data by calling a web call to your backend.